# contract.QueryFilter(Filter) Giving me errors in Ethers.js

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, bsc

Trying to get the any transfers that are coming from this address for this token but query filter is not working. I also am not really understanding the documentation from ether.js's website. The other examples I see are not putting any limit on the amount of blocks or have any other inputs.

Heres the error im getting. [image]

```
const bnbAddress = "0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c";

const tokenAbi = [
  "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)",
  "function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8)",
  "function name() public view returns (string)",
  "function symbol() public view returns (string)",
  "event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint amount)",
  "function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256)",
];

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
);

const TokenContract = new ethers.Contract(bnbAddress, tokenAbi, provider);

export const getListOfTransfers = async (pairAddress) => {
  console.log(pairAddress);

  let filter = TokenContract.filters.Transfer(pairAddress);
  console.log(filter);

  let eventsWith = await BNBTokenContract.queryFilter(filter);
  console.log(eventsWith);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the screenshot provided, the actual error beneath the huge error text is "exceed maximum block range 5000".

When you use `queryFilter`, by default it chooses 0 to `'latest'`.

Querying for huge number of blocks is computationally expensive and an easy tool for DoS attackers. To counter them, many node services have introduced this limit.

You can either run your own node (so that you won't have this limit), or you have to hack some code together to get your job done.

```
const startBlock = xx;
const endBlock = xx;
const allEvents = [];

for(let i = startBlock; i < endBlock; i += 5000) {
  const _startBlock = i;
  const _endBlock = Math.min(endBlock, i + 4999);
  const events = await BNBTokenContract.queryFilter(filter, _startBlock, _endBlock);
  allEvents = [...allEvents, ...events]
}
```

Comment: is the issue around querying a large number of blocks only applicable if the contract itself has a large number of transactions?  That is, when searching from 0 to 'latest', does it search only blocks which contain transactions for the contract that's been queried, or every block on the blockchain since the beginning of time?